# Upload file to SAP HANA backend

Tags: sapui5

I want to upload a picture using to fileUploader control. But the browser blocks me because CORS.

It is possible to upload on theirs backend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backend first needs to be added to the destinations in the HCP cockpit as shown:

[image]

And then you need to add the backend information in neo-app.json file. In this case, **data-monitoring** is my backend application.

```
   {
        "path": "/data-monitoring",
        "target": {
            "type": "destination",
            "name": "data-monitoring",
            "entryPath": "/data-monitoring-1.0.0"
        },
        "description": "Data Monitoring API"
    }
```